# Flash Loans on Etherscan

Tags: flash-loans

Is it possible to see all the transactions triggered by a single flash loan on etherscan?

Ex. could someone have called another contract from a single function that took a flash loan and this would be a separate event, or are all events triggered by a flash loan grouped on Etherscan?

Answer (score 0):

Flash loans only last for one transaction, so if you find a transaction where a flash loan is taken, it contains all the info about everything that has been done with it.

Comment: So this means that if I see, in one transaction, `wallet1 -> wallet2` and `wallet2 -> wallet1`, but I also see, in a different transaction, `wallet2 -> wallet3` and `wallet3 -> wallet2`, all for the same number of tokens, I can ensure that this wasn't the flash loan that triggered the other transaction? Essentially, I'm trying to figure out if the flow of money was actually `1->2->3->2->1` or whether these accounts are actually unconnected